# Failing to get quite simple i18n and dynamic routing to work with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

First things first - I've read the Next.js docs, passed the tutorial, looked at a number of examples, but at the end of the day, I am still failing to achieve a very simple thing with Next.js.

I have an application that has these locales: `en` and `de`.

The routes look like this:

```
/en/things/[id]
/de/things/[id]
```

So basically, I need to display some static texts in two languages that have nothing to do with the thing ID. These are just plain texts the same for all IDs. Then I have some AJAX that actually needs the ID from the path.

Now the troubles start:

1. If I don't have `getStaticProps` in the `things/[id].js`, I got this error:

```
Error: MISSING_MESSAGE: No messages were configured on the provider.
```

2. Then I add the `getStaticProps` like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps({locale}) {
  return {
    props: {
      messages: await import(`../messages/${locale}.json`)
    }
  }
}
```

and get this error:

```
Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/things/[id]'.
```

3. Then I add `getStaticPaths` like this:

```
export const getStaticPaths = () => ({
  paths: [],
  fallback: 'blocking'
})
```

because I have a million IDs, I cannot pre-generate all the pages. Also, new IDs appear after the deployment of the app, so I cannot list all possible IDs as paths during build time.

Now I get this error:

```
Error: Error serializing `.messages` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/things/[id]".
Reason: `object` ("[object Module]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

I cannot believe how such a simple thing can be so hard to achieve in a "framework" that claims to make life easier when working with React. I am trying to migrate an existing application from create-react-app to Next.js, but very simple things are so confusing to achieve.

Please, tell me how to achieve the following very simple thing:

1. Have one static page with static text in two languages: EN and DE.
2. Have users access the page like this: `/[locale]/things/[id]`.
3. Have some AJAX code that actually uses the thing ID from the URI path.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue! I can do one thing or the other thing, but not both.
I decided not to use getStaticPaths becuase I also have thousands of IDs, and I could pre-render just a few in the beginning, but it makes more sense to do it at request time. Now, if someone tries to access an a url like /orders/:id, it gets into an infinite redirect loop to itself (using a very dummy example from the docs as well)

Comment: but if I remove the i18n setup from the configs, it works.

Comment: ah, and in your case, the issue seems to be because you're not returning the locale to the paths in the getStaticPaths. You need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create 2 separate routes for local language instead setup [next-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next)
 it will automatically async your links according to selected local language.

Comment: I don't have 2 routes. I have 1 page/component, 1 route `/things/[id]`. The `en` | `de` part of the path is handled by the config. I am using `"next-intl": "2.3.3"`.

Comment: Try the package that I have mentioned it is very easy and has much popularity among the Next.js community and I have personally used it and much easier to configure.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get this working using `next-i18next` and `getServerSideProps`. Still, I am confused about why I had to convert my static page to a server-side rendered page just to get the translations working. Translations are just static texts and shouldn't require server-side rendering. I should be able to have them at build time.

Comment: yes next-i18next has component base translation you can use t function to do that. 
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
now inside component use Hook
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
inside return
        <h3 className="widget-title">{t("news-letter")}</h3>

Comment: @ric980 next.js i18n feature is not able to be used when exporting it to a static website (SSG), a workaround can be this: https://dev.to/adrai/static-html-export-with-i18n-compatibility-in-nextjs-8cd

Comment: @ric i managed using `getServerSideProps` as well. but it hurts runtime performance as It needs to reload the translation at runtime, how did you manage this issue?